# How to define and use a central color palette for UI elements?

Tags: ios

I'd like to define in one place a color palette and just use references to it, so I can change the palette in this one place without having to touch all UI elements to modify the color.

To clarify, here's how I would achieve the same thing in android:

- define a colors.xml:

```xml
<resources>
    <color name="main_text">#ffffffff</color>
</resources>
```

- use the colors like so:

```xml
<TextView ...
          android:text="foobar"
          android:textColor="@color/main_text"
        />
```

On iOS SDK the UI is usually not described by hand written xml. But I was wondering if there is any way to use some sort of a reference to a color in IB and then redefine the color later. (I don't need to see the final colors in the xcode preview either.)

So far the only solution I found would be to use the view tags: define a tag for each element, get those at runtime, cast to the correct class and start applying the color. Which is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a category for the UIColor class. That way, you can declare additional colors like this:

```
+ (UIColor *)lightBlueColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:132.0f / 255.0f green:207.0f / 255.0f blue:218.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}
```

And then use them just like you would any other color:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightBlueColor]];
```

Otherwise, you could consider subclassing what ever UI element you want to recolor. That way, you could make the color modifications in `initWithCoder:` and then reference the subclass in Interface Builder.

Comment: Subclassing is an excellent suggestion! I can easily define a couple of my own UILabels classes (and what not), and set the different colors in initWithCoder: as you suggest.

I'll wait for just a bit longer in case someone has an even better solution, but I think this one is very elegant.

As for the category suggestion: Yes indeed that would be my central place for the color definitions.